# MYSQL Join Query w/ 3 Tables and Multiple Columns

Tags: mysql

Trying to fetch the proper data but am running in to some problems. I want to join all 3 tables and want any easy way to query move names based on the moves selected in the users move set.

User Table

```
userid | name 
----------------
 1     | Steve 
 2     | Mike  
 3     | Aaron  
 4     | Chris
```

Move Table

```
moveid | movename 
------------------
 1     | Sit      
 2     | Stand    
 3     | Lay      
 4     | Run
```

Moveset Table

```
movesetid | userid | move1 | move2 | move3
----------------------------------
 1        | 1      | 3     |  5    | 7
 2        | 2      | 5     |  9    | 6
 3        | 2      | 1     |  12   | 1
 4        | 4      | 8     |  4    | 10
```

** I would like to get a result where I can query a userid and get a list of move names that correspond to their move set. i.e.: Sit, Run, Lay **

Comment: Are you trying to replace the move names in each column on moveset when selecting?

Comment: I am trying to output just the move names based on querying the userid which in turn queries the moveset table, gets all the moves belonging to the userid by the moveid in each column(move1, move2, move3), matches each move from the moveset and spits out the move name.

Answer (score 0):

You'd first join User to MoveSet to get the users moves, then do 3 additional joins on those columns:

```
SELECT
    u.userid,
    u.name,
    m1.movename,
    m2.movename,
    m3.movename
FROM
    User u
LEFT JOIN MoveSet ms ON ms.userid = u.userid
LEFT JOIN Move m1 ON m1.moveid = ms.move1
LEFT JOIN Move m2 ON m2.moveid = ms.move2
LEFT JOIN Move m3 ON m3.moveid = ms.move3
WHERE u.userid = YourQueryId;
```